# Global Dark Theme option is not working in Gnome Tweak Tools?

Tags: gnome, gnome-tweak-tool

it toggles On/Off but it doesn't make any changes

my nautilus background is still white, settings is still white, everything is still white[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Global Dark theme option will only work if the theme in question supports it. In other word, the theme supplies alternative assets and css for this. But Your theme "MacBuntu OS" doesn't provide any such files. That's why it won't work.

Comment: oh that's a bummer

Comment: Yeah. It's an old theme too. Basically I will be grateful seeing any old theme working in GNOME3. They change specs so frequently

Comment: i'm running 3.20 and it's working fine apart from that dark theme thing

Comment: then, how can i fix it? how can I make it work?